# making set method of useState hook to wait for the variable update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, infinite-scroll

I have a use case where I am using the useState hook to increment value of the variable. Once the value of the variable is incremented then only I need to call a update function.

```
const [page, setPage] = useState(1);

const fetchMoreData = () => {
        setPage(page+1);
        updateNews();
};
```

So in essence I wanted it to be something like `await setPage(page+1);`. So that once the page is updated then only I fetch the news from the update URL page.

Due to this currently I am getting

```
index.js:1 Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `https://english.jagran.com/trending/did-mars-ever-look-like-earth-heres-what-top-nasa-scientist-has-to-say-10033695`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at InfiniteScroll (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:32922:24)
    at News (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:775:89)
    at Route (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:34951:29)
    at Switch (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:35153:29)
    at div
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:34582:30)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:34203:35)
    at App
```

This is my component **News.js** currently

```
const News = (props)=>{
    const [articles, setArticles] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
    const [totalResults, setTotalResults] = useState(0);

    const capitalizeFirstLetter = (string)=> {
        return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
    }

    const updateNews = async ()=>{
        props.setProgress(10);
        let goToPage = page;
        const url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=${props.country}&category=${props.category}&apiKey=${props.apiKey}&page=${goToPage}&pageSize=${props.pageSize}`;
        props.setProgress(30);
        let data = await fetch(url);
        props.setProgress(50);
        let parsedData = await data.json();
        props.setProgress(70);
        if(parsedData)
        {
            setArticles(articles.concat(parsedData.articles));
            setLoading(false);
            setPage(page);
            setTotalResults(parsedData.totalResults);
        }
        props.setProgress(100);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        updateNews();
        // eslint-disable-next-line
    }, [])

    const fetchMoreData = () => {
        setPage(page+1);
        updateNews();
    };
        return (
        <>
            <h3 className="text-center" style={{marginTop:'4%'}}>NewsMonkey - Top {`${capitalizeFirstLetter(props.category)}`} Headlines</h3>
            {loading && <Spinner/>}
            <InfiniteScroll
            dataLength={articles.length}
            next={fetchMoreData}
            hasMore={articles.length < totalResults}
            loader={<Spinner/>}
            >
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                {articles.map((element)=>{
                    return (
                    <div className="col-md-4" key={element.url}>
                        <NewsItem title={element && element.title?element.title.slice(0, 45): ""} description={element && element.description?element.description.slice(0, 50):""}
                        imageUrl={element.urlToImage}
                        newsUrl ={element.url}
                        author={element.author}
                        date={element.publishedAt}
                        source={element.source.name}/>
                    </div>
                )})}
                </div>
            </div>
            </InfiniteScroll>
            
        </>
    )
}


export default News
```

I tried printing the value of `goToPage` in the update function and as I could see it was 1 every time.
Is there any way to resolve the error or wait for setPage.

**Note :** I tried the solution to the question which I was getting as suggestion to this question, but that did not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want to increment `page` property, you probably should use `setPage` with callback function, like this:

```
setPage(page => page + 1);
```

2. You can achieve desired effect by using `useEffect` with `page` in dependency array:

```
useEffect(() => {
  updateNews();
}, [page])
```

Comment: I need that useEffect to be triggered every time fetchMoreData is called, how can i do that?

Comment: Make it dependent on a state property that is changed when `fetchMoreData` completes.